# OpenCL - Support different platforms with the same binary

Tags: cross-platform, opencl, gpgpu

**Question 1**
If I want to build an application with OpenCL support, do I have any guarantees that the `OpenCL.lib` implementation from my vendor is able to work with all devices from other Vendors? If yes what's the difference between the implementation?

**Question 2**
Is it possible to use different OpenCL versions in the same application? For example AMD has released a preview driver for `OpenCL 2.0` support. On the other hand the lovely company called Nvidia is still trying to ignore everything past `OpenCL 1.1`. It would be nice if I could write platform specific code in different versions.

Comment: Based on personal experience (notebook with Intel IGPU & CPU + Radeon GPU on Windows7), answer to question 1 is positive. When I loaded platforms list & looked at cl_platform_id in VS2013 debugger, deep in guts I saw that 2 libraries are dynamically loaded - one for AMD & one for Intel. Though, I don't know what is the general case. For question 2 - backwards compatibility exists (symbols will be found in libraries).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I've experienced 1 myself - I'm looking for the general behavior (couldn't find anything). Thanks for answering 2! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1: On Windows, OpenCL.lib is a static wrapper around OpenCL.dll, which is the ICD loader, and exposes *all* of the available platforms. It is provided by Khronos and redistributed by the OpenCL platform vendors. So go ahead and link to it; it will work with whatever is installed (although if *nothing* is installed your application won't run because it can't find OpenCL.dll; this is solved other ways).

2: Yes. As long as the ICD loader is the latest, you can get at the newer API on newer platforms / devices. Just don't use new API on old devices; that will crash or worse.

Comment: I'll add that unless you NEED newer API, a safe way to target both older and newer platforms / devices is to use the 1.1 cl.h header file (since it doesn't include the 1.2 or newer API).

Comment: Good answer! Never heard of the ICD loader before: Can be found here: http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-icd-1.2.11.0.tgz